# AS3 Load library movie based on parameter on Parent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have following scenario:

I have created a movie symbol at library called `mov_Child`. Which has `dynamic` text field. But I have to pass parent movies text value to the mov_Child's dynamic text field.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give instance name to `dynamic` textfield e.g. "myTextField"

```
var parentMoviesText:String = "This is parent movies text";

mov_Child.myTextField.text = parentMoviesText; // Here you pass the text value
```